# File isn't being read? (C++)

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I am attempting to read numbers from a text file into a program, but for some reason, the program isn't reading the file. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{

ifstream infile; 

infile.open ("adventDay1.txt"); 

if (!infile) { //Check if file is opening 

    cerr << "Error!"<< endl;

    return 0; 
}

int dataSize = 0;
infile >> dataSize; 
int* arr; 
arr = new int[dataSize]; //dynamically allocated array

int measureCount = 0; //Keep track of input from file 


for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {

   // infile >> dataSize; 

    arr[i] = dataSize;

    measureCount += 1; 
}

 cout << measureCount << endl; 

delete[] arr; //Delete dynamically allocated memory 
return 0; 
}
```

Each time I run it, it just displays the "Error!" message I added. There are 2,000 numbers in the text file, so that should be the expected output based on what I have here. I can't pinpoint the mistake.

Comment: Program working directory can be different from one where the source file is. As a first step, start from the full file path.

Comment: As a troubleshooting aid, you can use [`std::filesystem::current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) to find where your program is "looking for" the file. Requires C++17 (which you should be using).

Comment: @S.M. Ok, the full path resolved the issue. For whatever reason, it's only displaying the first number in the file now, but I think I can debug from here. Thank you!

Comment: And if you're not compiling to c++17 for some reason, the POSIX `getcwd` function may be useful as is opening a file with a distinctive name, writing to it, closing it and then searching the computer for the file.

Comment: I recommend creating file, something with a recognizable filename, writing "Hello\n" to it.  Run your program and search the directories for this file.  The location of this file is the default location for all your files.  Move your data text file to this location.  **Or** specify the absolute path in the filename.

Comment: *"it just displays the "Error!" message I added."* -- Immediately after the line that produces this message is `return 0;`. So you've shown that no attempt is ever made to read from the file; the program exits before reaching those lines. This is good debugging. However, your title (and question) is off. Correct, but imprecise. More precise than *"File isn't being read"* is *"File isn't being opened"*. Details like that matter when debugging!

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you! I hadn't even realized this could create an issue.

Answer (score -2):

Include fstream and ensure that you are opening the file in read mode. Perhaps also define it as `ifstream infile("adventDay1.txt")`

Comment: including `fstream` is best-practice (include what you use), but this must be compiling as-is if they're able to run it and get the "Error!" message. Using the constructor that accepts the filename can also save lines of code, and is another best practice, but wouldn't lead to this problem, since the `open` method is called directly after stream creation.